# Need to identify special characters in filename

Tags: regex, powershell, sharepoint

I'm little weak in Regex, so I need help to check if filename has these special characters #%&*:<>?/{|}

I tried this, but it's not working:

```
$pattern = [regex]::Escape("#%&*:<>?/{|}")
$filename = "XYZEF_MNY_001.SOW.AMD#2.08AUG2018-07AUG2019.pdf"
If($filename -match $pattern){
 write-host "Yes, file has special chars"
}
```

It's not showing the desired result..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want the special characters in a character class, for example:

```
[#%&*:<>?/{|}]
```

You won’t want to use `Escape` either (see mklement’s comment below):

```
$pattern = "[#%&*:<>?/{|}]"
```

<sub>*note: I'm not a powershell user, although I would imagine the principle of character classes would be similar.</sub>

Comment: Good point about the character class, but you definitely do _not_ want to escape the list of characters _including the enclosing `[...]`_, so I suggest removing that part. PowerShell uses the .NET [`System.Text.RegularExpression.Regex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex) type, which supports virtually all modern regex constructs. As an aside: To eliminate potentially unwanted side effects from string interpolation in `"..."` strings, it's generally better to use verbatim `'...'` strings for regexes in PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

As I'L'L mentioned, use the character class to achieve this:

```
$pattern = "[#%&*:<>?/{|}]"
$filename = "XYZEF_MNY_001.SOW.AMD#2.08AUG2018-07AUG2019.pdf"
If($filename -match $pattern){
 write-host "Yes, file has special chars"
}
```

[image]

Reference:

https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-regex.html